# Groovy groupby or map for a sql

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have written the following query

```
def result=GuruActivity.executeQuery("select P.id, P.postBy, P.totalUp from GuruActivity as P where P.totalUp>5")
println result
render "done"
```

I am getting result like

```
[1, AAA, 7], [2, AAA, 10], [3, AAA, 7], [7, BBB, 7], [9, CCC, 7]
```

Now how do get the P.ID in the following format (in a map) here i am getting the id that are over 5 totalUp

```
AAA : [1,2,3]
BBB : [7]
CCC : [9]
```

How do i do this?

Comment: You could use GROUP_CONCAT, or just manipulate the array in you application level code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use collection's `groupBy`.

```
def list = [[1, 'AAA', 7], [2, 'AAA', 10], 
           [3, 'AAA', 7], [7, 'BBB', 7], [9, 'CCC', 7]]

assert list.groupBy{it[1]}
           .collectEntries{k, v-> [k, v.collect{it[0]}]} == 
                          ['AAA':[1, 2, 3], 'BBB':[7], 'CCC':[9]]​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Another would be inject

```
list.inject( [:].withDefault { [] } ) { m, e ->
    m[ e[ 1 ] ] << e[ 0 ]
    m
}
```